# In dart how to extend a custom PolymerElement with PaperInputBehavior?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Basically I try to do a port of `GoldCcCvcInput` to a dart implementation, instead of wrapping of a js implementation.

Looking at this:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-cc-cvc-input/blob/master/gold-cc-cvc-input.html
Together with https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/behaviors

Something like:

```
 @PolymerRegister('nbdate-input')
 class NbdateInput extends PolymerElement with PaperInputBehavior,
 IronControlState, IronA11yKeysBehavior ...
```

Minimal test project 
https://github.com/jonboj/inputbehavior-dart.git

The project initialize without dumping any error messages and displays the iron-input elements ok. But when one of the iron-input elements are put in focus, the exception below is dumped in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
  Polymer.PaperInputBehaviorImpl._onFocus   
  handler   
  Polymer.Base._addFeature.fire 
  Polymer.IronControlState._focusBlurHandler
```

This has an override of method `onFocusedChanged` https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-cc-cvc-input/blob/master/gold-cc-cvc-input.html#L219

In dart a corresponding Observer is triggered, with a printout occurring after the exception dump.

https://github.com/jonboj/inputbehavior-dart/blob/master/lib/nbdatebehavior_input.dart#L56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case the needed functionality was provided by

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container

With Dart following the structure of last example (Social Security Number) in
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-input

Answer (score 1):

I would check the console for errors, the mixin ordering doesn't look like it is correct and it should give you the desired ordering in a message, which may solve your issue (I would expect an ordering like this `IronA11yKeysBehavior, IronControlState, PaperInputBehavior`).

Additionally, make sure you are calling `polymerCreated()` in your constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Now I have edited the question with more info and an example repo. Checked up on *) With order `IronA11yKeysBehavior, IronControlState, PaperInputBehavior`  It dumps an exception in the console at initialization, with the  order of the mixin. *) Accroding to api  'polymerCreated()` will be invoked at `NbdatebehaviorInput.created() : super.created()`

Comment: I have looked further into this. Maybe the needed functionality could be obtained by putting things in a `<paper-input-container>`, perhaps also what is intended by the framework. I will investigate this further.